# What are the default QuickLook plugins in /System/Library/QuickLook/ under OS X 10.8?

Tags: macos, quicklook

I want to see if I have any extra .qlgenerator files there, or if I'm missing any.

If someone with a recent or (better yet) new clean install could list the files in that folder, OR if anyone knows where I could find an official list from Apple, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

I try to do what I can, unfortunately I did not exactly 10.8, I would like to point out that the following list is for

```
System Version: OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
```

`Audio.qlgenerator
Bookmark.qlgenerat
Clippings.qlgenera
Contact.qlgenerato
EPS.qlgenerator
Font.qlgenerator
Icon.qlgenerator
Image.qlgenerator
LocPDF.qlgenerator
Mail.qlgenerator
Movie.qlgenerator
Notes.qlgenerator
Office.qlgenerator
PDF.qlgenerator
Package.qlgenerato
SceneKit.qlgenerat
Security.qlgenerat
StandardBundles.ql
Text.qlgenerator
Web.qlgenerator
iCal.qlgenerator
iChat.qlgenerator`

Then in addition to `/System/Library/QuickLook/`
there is also `/Library/QuickLook/` 
where I found:

`iBooksAuthor.qlgenerator
iWork.qlgenerator`